# Dapper Extensions custom ClassMapper isn't called on Insert()

Tags: automapper, sql-insert, dapper, composite-primary-key, dapper-extensions

I'm using Dapper Extensions and have defined my own custom mapper to deal with entities with composite keys.

```
     public class MyClassMapper<T> : ClassMapper<T> where T : class
{
    public MyClassMapper()
    {
        // Manage unmappable attributes

        IList<PropertyInfo> toIgnore = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => !x.CanWrite).ToList();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in toIgnore.ToList())
        {
            Map(propertyInfo).Ignore();
        }

        // Manage keys

        IList<PropertyInfo> propsWithId = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Id") || x.Name.EndsWith("ID")).ToList();
        PropertyInfo primaryKey = propsWithId.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x.Name, $"{nameof(T)}Id", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (primaryKey != null && primaryKey.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            Map(primaryKey).Key(KeyType.Identity);
        }
        else if (propsWithId.Any())
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propsWithId)
            {
                Map(prop).Key(KeyType.Assigned);
            }
        }

        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

I also have this test case to test my mapper:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestMyAutoMapper()
    {
        DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.DefaultMapper = typeof(MyClassMapper<>);

        MySubscribtionEntityWithCompositeKey entity = new MySubscribtionEntityWithCompositeKey
        {
            SubscriptionID = 145,
            CustomerPackageID = 32
        };

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var result = connection.Insert(entity);
            var key1 = result.SubscriptionID;
            var key2 = result.CustomerPackageID;
        }
    }
```

Note that I set the default mapper in the test case.

The insert fails and I notive that my customer mapper is never called. I have no documentation on the github page on the topic, so I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do to make dapper extensions use my mapper.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your question, you are *attempting* to write your own *defalut* class mapper derived from the existing one. I never used this approach; so I do not know why it is not working or whether it should work.

I explicitly map the classes as below:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CustomerMapper : ClassMapper<Customer>
{
    public CustomerMapper()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Customer");
        Map(x => x.CustomerID).Key(KeyType.Identity);
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

The `AutoMap()` will map rest of the properties based on [conventions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions#naming-conventions). Please refer to [these](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/KeyTypes) [two](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper) resources for more information about mapping.

Then I call `SetMappingAssemblies` at the startup of the project as below:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
```

The `GetExecutingAssembly()` is used in above code because mapping classes (`CustomerMapper` and other) are in same assembly which is executing. If those classes are placed in other assembly, provide *that* assembly instead.

And that's it, it works.

To set the dialect, I call following line just below the `SetMappingAssemblies`:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new DapperExtensions.Sql.SqlServerDialect();
```

Use your preferred dialect instead of `SqlServerDialect`.

Apparently, the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper#customized-pluralizedautoclassmapper) may help you achieve what you are actually trying to. But, I cannot be sure, as I said above, I never used it.