# Why DapperExtensions GetById not returning the object?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper, dapper-extensions

I'm using DapperExtensions and the framework I'm using is .NET-Core.

I have a base repository with the following:

```
public abstract class TableRepository<T> : ITableRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public T GetById(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection.ConnectionString))
        {
            return sqlConnection.Get<T>(id);
        }
    }

   ....
}
```

The `ITableRepository` contains multiple methods, but in this specific scenario we are interested in the `GetById` method:

```
public interface ITableRepository<T>
{
   T GetById(int id);
   ...
}
```

I have a `ISkipRepository` interface which inherits from `ITableRepository` and also defines the type:

```
public interface ISkipRepository : ITableRepository<Skip>
{
     Skip GetByName(string name);
     bool Exists(int id, string name);
}
```

I have an instance of `ISkipRepository` like so:

```
public class SkipRepository : TableRepository<Skip>, ISkipRepository
{
    public SkipRepository(IDbConnection dbConnection) : base(dbConnection) { }

    public Skip GetByName(string name)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [Skip] WHERE [Name] = @name";

        object parameters = new
        {
            name
        };

        return QuerySingle(sql, parameters, CommandType.Text);
    }

    public bool Exists(int id, string name)
    {
        var group = new PredicateGroup { Operator = GroupOperator.And, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>() };
        group.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Skip>(s => s.Id, Operator.Eq, id, true));
        group.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<Skip>(s => s.Name, Operator.Eq, name));
        return Exists(group);
    }
}
```

I've register this instance in my `Startup`:

```
services.AddTransient<ISkipRepository, SkipRepository>();
```

And calling the `GetById` on `SkipRepository` like so:

```
var skip = _skipRepository.GetById(skipId);
```

In my table I only have 3 records and as you can see I'm trying to grab a `Skip` by `Id`.

Here is my domain object:

```
public class Skip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerDayAfter14Days { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a dapper mapper class for my `Skip`:

```
public sealed class SkipMapper : ClassMapper<Skip>
{
    public SkipMapper()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Skip");
        Map(x => x.Id).Key(KeyType.Identity);
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the `GetById` throws an exception indicating that it expects 1 element but has got 3 elements.

My database table has 3 records and so I started to dig deeper and run a SQL Profiler to what I found this query:

```
SELECT [y_1].[Id] AS [c_0], [y_1].[Name] AS [c_1], [y_1].[Description] AS [c_2], [y_1].[BasePrice] AS [c_3], [y_1].[PricePerDayAfter14Days] AS [c_4], [y_1].[Quantity] AS [c_5] FROM [Skip] [y_1]
```

As you can see its not added a `WHERE` clause and I'm struggling to understand why.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Update:

I've removed all the layers and done this directly in my Controller:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=develop;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
        {
            Data.Models.Skip skipModel = conn.Get<Data.Models.Skip>(1);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Is it possible that your `Key` attribute is changing the behavior? What happens if you remove it and let the standard `Id` convention take over?

Comment: @DavidL Just removed it and still no luck

Comment: The Id is an `identity` column?  Otherwise use `ExplicitKey`. Add the table attribute. Check the [Docs](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper-contrib)

Comment: @Max That appears to be Dapper.Contrib, I'm not using this NuGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mapping the primary key using `[Key]` attribute. This mapping does not work with Dapper Extensions; it is picking up the convention based mapping (the property named `Id`) currently. Just to be sure, please map explicitly like below:

```
public sealed class ProductMapper : ClassMapper<Product>
{
    public ProductMapper()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Products");
        Map(x => x.Id).Key(KeyType.Guid);
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

You also need to call `SetMappingAssemblies` at the startup of the project to apply these mappings.
Also, set the dialect at startup just after `SetMappingAssemblies` like below:

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new DapperExtensions.Sql.SqlServerDialect();
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691026/5779732) answer to learn more about mappings in Dapper Extensions.

---

I copied your code below and executed on my system.
Dapper: 1.50.4.0.
DapperExtensions: 1.6.3.0.
Target .NET Framework: 4.6.1; NOT Core.

```
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() });
DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SqlDialect = new DapperExtensions.Sql.SqlServerDialect();

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    Skip skip = conn.Get<Skip>(1);
}

public class Skip
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal BasePrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PricePerDayAfter14Days { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public sealed class SkipMapper : ClassMapper<Skip>
{
    public SkipMapper()
    {
        Schema("dbo");
        Table("Skip");
        Map(x => x.Id).Key(KeyType.Identity);
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

This generates following SQL query which is correct.

```
SELECT [dbo].[Skip].[Id], [dbo].[Skip].[Name], [dbo].[Skip].[Description], [dbo].[Skip].[BasePrice], [dbo].[Skip].[PricePerDayAfter14Days], [dbo].[Skip].[Quantity] FROM [dbo].[Skip] WHERE ([dbo].[Skip].[Id] = @Id_0)
```

I think there is something wrong in your layers or may be upper version is buggy.

Comment: Actually, I say a lie. I doubled check my profiler and this is the SQL which is churned out: SELECT [y_1].[Id] AS [c_0], [y_1].[Name] AS [c_1], [y_1].[Description] AS [c_2], [y_1].[BasePrice] AS [c_3], [y_1].[PricePerDayAfter14Days] AS [c_4], [y_1].[Quantity] AS [c_5] FROM [dbo].[Skip] [y_1]
 WHERE (1=1)

Comment: Interestingly, neither the '1' in (1=1) is the parameter as I've passed in 3 within the Get<T>() and it still says (1=1)

Comment: Okay.. this is weird. Pointing to the EXACT same database but using a .NET project with the same Dapper and DapperExtension versions as you WORKS! So we can rule out the database being a cause (if something wasn't set right in the DB) it's definitely something to do with the versions or framework

Comment: I've just updated Dapper to 2.0.123 and DapperExtensions to 1.7.0 and it doesn't work. So we can rule out the framework now! Glad to finally make progress on this shitty issue! I'll now test your Dapper and DapperExtension versions in my original project. Fingers crossed